# Como deleto um commit do histórico do github?

Tags: git, github, commit

Gostaria de apagar um commit feito no github mas SEM excluir as alterações, motivo descobri que em um de meus arquivos no código continha informações pessoais e ao altera-lo essas informações ainda poderiam ser vistas no histórico de commit, ou seja, quero excluir exatamente o commit do histórico. Como posso fazer isso?

Coisas das quais tentei removem o commit e também as alterações feitas: 
**git reset --hard HEAD^** (Volta a commits anteriores e remove as alterações feitas após este commit)

Comment: Lucas, já vi formas de apagar todo o histórico, apenas um nunca vi... Apagar tudo, te atende?

Comment: entra no git vai nos commits e apaga pelo menos no gitLab é assim

Comment: olha pode funcionar, como que faz?

Answer (score 2):

Lucas, tenta seguir esses passos:

```
git checkout --orphan latest_branch

git add -A

git commit -am "commit message"

git branch -D master

git branch -m master

git push -f origin master
```

Já fiz isso, funcionou, me base-ei na seguinte resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716658/how-to-delete-all-commit-history-in-github

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado o/

Comment: Muito bom, exatamente o que eu precisava!