# Como alterar um arquivo de commit antigo no git?

Tags: git, github, commit

Tenho um arquivo no qual acabei colocando uma senha real em um commit antigo e agora gostaria de alterar este arquivo para não deixar exposto.
Encontrei um post aqui no stack mas acho que deve estar desatualizado, é de 2015.
No post pede para usar o comando:

```
git rebase --interactive b6f925df^
```

Depois altere `pick` para `edit` nos commits que desejo modificar.

Este é o problema, não consegui fazer essa alteração de pick para edit. Quando executo o comando rebase, abre um editor mas não consigo fazer nada deste editor.

Alguém pode me dar uma força?

Comment: Meu palpite é que esse editor seja o [Vim](https://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa14/tutorial/git/config.html). Se for, basta digitar `i` para entrar no modo de inserção, editar o que precisa, depois `ESC`, e `:x`. Ou você pode [configurar o Git para usar outro editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596805)

Answer (score 0):

O git possui uma instrução chamada **log** o mesmo tem o seguinte proposito mostra os logs de confirmação e listar os commits que são alcançáveis ​​seguindo os parent links.
Cada commit que foi descrito a modificação pode ser recuperada.

```
$git log

commit 4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx18e7 (HEAD -> master)
Author: alguen <emgail_fantasia@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 15 08:06:47 2018 -0400

     info 

commit 4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx84ee (tag: 1.0.00)
Author: alguen <emgail_fantasia@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 15 07:52:39 2018 -0400

    alts - add
```

O git sempre armazena uma hash do commit "**commit 4xxxxxxxxxx**" o commit do topo é inalterável pois foi o ultimo; para alterar  o primeiro tem que pegar a segunda hash do segundo commit( sempre um commit abaixo para alterar o de cima)

A uma instrução parecida com reset que possui funções para recuperar.
`soft`: volta ao commit do arquivo e estara em statement com a modificação
pronta
`mixed` : vai retornar antes do statement voltara para modifeid
`hard`: mata todo o commit e tudo que foi feito nele
**uso:**

```
git reset --soft 4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx84ee
```

ao utilizar `git status`    sera apresentado as modificações assim refaze-la

Answer (score -2):

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
    git checkout --orphan latest_branch
    
    git add -A
    
    git commit -am "commit message"
    
    git branch -D master
    
    git branch -m master
    
    git push -f origin master
```

Fonte: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401836/como-deleto-um-commit-do-histórico-do-github](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401836/como-deleto-um-commit-do-hist%C3%B3rico-do-github)

**Dica**: Eu mantenhos dados sensiveis fora do repositório do git e faço um import deles quando compilo o código ou via parâmetro. Veja se a linguagem na qual está trabalhando aceita isto.